# Rewrite Rule mod_rewrite rule

Tags: php, mysql, mod-rewrite

Please I have the following

```
RewriteRule ^m/([a-z]+)$ view_site_public.php?site_name=$1
```

What I want to is to have http://www.site.com/m/cool at the address bar resolve internally to

http://www.site.com/view_site_public.php?site_name=cool

It is currently giving error

Comment: You should post your full .htaccess file and the error you are getting in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/m/([a-z]+)$ view_site_public.php?site_name=$1
```

By the way, you are only capture lowercase letters in the site name. Is that what you want?

You may also want to add [QSA,L] at the end of that RewriteRule, so that you aren't checking any other rules and so you also pass in any query string params that the user specifies.

Comment: Thank you. please how can i also capture UPPERCASE letters.

Comment: [a-zA-Z] or you might want numbers, underscores, periods, etc. You can keep adding: [a-zA-z0-9_.] OR, you could just do [^/?] to match anything but forward slash and question mark.

Comment: This Worked Perfect. - RewriteRule ^m/([^/?]+)$ view_site_public.php?site_name=$1